# Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_decrypt()

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, php-openssl

I am using xampp and windows along with laravel, everything was working fine, but when I finished work and turned of xampp and try to open my work today morning, this is what I get:

```
FatalThrowableError in Encrypter.php line 100:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_decrypt()
```

Encrypter.php is a standard laravel file and I have not even touched it. My extension is turned on.

extension=php_openssl.dll

What might be wrong?

Comment: It looks like the method Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_decrypt is not reachable or being loaded. Have you done something with the autoloader?

Comment: Nope I have not even touched autoloader, trust me it was working fine before I shut xampp down and next time when I ran it this is what I get

Comment: I trust you ^^ Just highlithing the fact that if a function is undefined, is because is not being loaded. If you are sure that the extension is being loaded, then the only thing that's possible to be the failing point, is the loading of the file. Try verifying the reading permissions of that file or the folders above it.

Comment: So how would I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have shut XAMPP down and restarted it, it may be worth running the `composer install` command again, or simply running `composer update` to ensure that all dependancies are being loaded correctly.

Comment: Hmm seems like there is a problem: cannot update or install apparently these files cannot be found. one of them is the one I get error message

Comment: There you have your error, you cannot find the files, then obviously the files aren't being loaded.

Comment: Yeap exactly, I have specified exact location of these files so C:\\xampp\php\ext and works fine, got another problem with database to fix haha

Comment: I even hadn't the composer installed, fixed after installation, thanks

Answer (score 25):

Just edit php.ini file and uncomment by removing ";" before this line --extension=openssl. in php.ini file. and it will start working properly.

Comment: Mine issue was starter after uncommenting this line.

Comment: This fixed mine. tnx.

Answer (score 9):

Modify **php.ini** and enable **openssl** extension in you php environment.

To find php installation path, run below command in **terminal** or **cmd**

> `php --ini`

Output something like below:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\php-7.3.8\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

here mine is
**Loaded Configuration File** is `C:\php-7.3.8\php.ini`

open php.ini with any editor using vim, nano, notepad++ or any editor.

find `extension=openssl` remove `;`

> from `;extension=openssl`
> to `extension=openssl`

save and restart server.

Comment: Oh. then please share here, or ans to this question, if you figured out in future. Best of luck..cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
composer install
```

didn't fix the problem, but the following does:

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also arise if incorrect `php.ini` file is loaded.
Make sure in your config `php_module` is defined in the `httpd.conf`

```
<IfModule php_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi! I had this same issue, I [got these dlls](https://www.dll-files.com/search/?q=api-ms-win-crt) and YAY openssl.dll is working again.** Try this in the cmd:

> **C:\php> .\deplister.exe .\ext\php_openssl.dll**
> php8.dll,OK
> libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll,OK
> libssl-1_1-x64.dll,OK
> CRYPT32.dll,OK
> KERNEL32.dll,OK
> WS2_32.dll,OK
> VCRUNTIME140.dll,OK
> api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll,OK api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll,OK
> api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll,OK
> api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll,OK
> api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll,OK
> api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll,OK
> api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll,OK api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll,OK